# how to make async=false and alwaysSessionAsync=false work on a vm transport?

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

i need to implement a messaging scenario that consumes messages from throusands of destinations (topics). As the throughput on these topics is very low i'm using springs `simplemessagelistenercontainer` to let activemq push the message into the appropriate listener.

alwaysSessionAsync=false makes sure that my vm connection to the embedded broker does NOT create one thread per session (as i have one session per listener and thousands of listeners).

like this my config starts the simplemessagelistenercontainer in the internal activemq task thread and the container schedules it into a thread pool. unfortunately the activemq task threads are very slow.

So i would like to use the async=false (NOT jms.sendAsync) to use the message sending thread to handle the message and push it into the listener where its scheduled into the handler thread pool.

Unfortunately this causes a deadlock (according to yourkit).

How can i make these two properties work?
or alternatively: how can i speed up the embedded activemq for async sends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async=false&amp;jms.copyMessageOnSend=false&amp;jms.useAsyncSend=false&amp;jms.alwaysSessionAsync=false&amp;jms.dispatchAsync=false`

does what i wanted to do. but if you send a message while consuming one this will create a deadlock.